# prepareForSegue is passing value by Reference to Destination view Controller

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-storyboard

I am using storyboard in one of my application and while passing a property from SourceViewController to DestinationViewController in prepareForSegue method the property being passed is passed by reference instead of passed by value. Which is causing some trouble for me as in Destination View Controller if user fiddles with the values and taps on back then I get an updated value in my SourceViewController which I do not want.

Please see the following to get more information on the issue

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DestinationView"])
    {
        DestinationViewController  *destinationViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        [destinationViewController setActivity:activity];
        //Here the value of activity is passed by reference. I have verified the same by checking the address of activity variable in Variable pane of Xcode in Source and destination view controller
}
```

Now I am not sure how to only pass the value and not the reference in the above case.

Comment: AFAIK objective C uses pass-by-value only. In your case, it passes the activity's pointer address. no?

Comment: @Alex Yes it was indeed passing the activity's pointer address

Comment: you can still create a copy, as explained by Lithu, but I'm not sure that's really a good idea, since it might use up a lot of memory for nothing. At this point you don't have much options other than making the fields read only - e.g. disable user interaction - using a static boolean flag that you pass to your class prior to segue. You can also implement a state machine (google FSM library) and check the state prior to saving a field content. This will remove the hassle of going through each field and selectively disabling each....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use a copy of it

```
    [destinationViewController setActivity:[activity copy]];
```

Implement its delegate copywithZone if needed

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
```